# error message: "The certificate is not valid for any server names"

Tags: https, error, firefox

I'm working on creating a self-signed SSL certificate for testing HTTPS on my local development platform.

When I browse with Firefox to a HTTPS test page I am seeing: `The certificate is not valid for any server names` as one of the two warning messages, the other one is related to the fact that the certificate is self-signed.

[image: Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer]

So how do I make the certificate valid for my server, which in my case is localhost?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix 2 things:

- First make sure the DN (distinguished name) is your server name, in my case 'localhost'
- Restart Apache

I wasn't restarting Apache which took me awhile to realize is necessary.

And it wasn't clear that DN was where I needed to stuff the hostname.  Normally, as far as I could tell, DN is used for your personal name.